# Do I need to add layout to a custom field in change set?

Tags: deployment, change-set

I have created a custom field in my sandbox, with different permissions and views for different profiles, on the page layout (Opportunity).

When building the change set, I added the custom field, but the layout did not come in the "Show Dependencies".

Do I need to add the page layout?
Do I need to add the profiles?

Comment: Yes to both, if you want your updates to be pushed in Production as they're on Sandbox. (PS: Profiles are added in the separate list at the bottom of Change Set. The field and the layout must be included in the same Change-Set together with the Profile in order for permissions to be correctly deployed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes to both, if you want your updates to be pushed in Production as they're on Sandbox. (PS: Profiles are added in the separate list at the bottom of Change Set.)

The field and the layout needs to be included in the same Change-Set together with the Profile in order for permissions to be correctly deployed.